# "Can't set headers after they are sent." error in node when getting data via angular

Tags: node.js, angular, http-headers

I am using angular 6 and I want to have a form filled as soon as the page loads, it never gets empty and it can be submitted at any time.

In my form I have a two-way binding

`first name <input type="text" id="firstname" [(ngModel)]="firstname" name="firstname"  >`

in the component I have

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getProfile(this.user_id).subscribe((data) =>{
      if(data.success){
        this.firstname = data.firstname;
    })
  }
```

So, as soon as the page loads I am filling the form, and due to the two-way binding, the form is never empty (unless user erases everything on purpose, in that case angular checks for empty fields and does not submit. ). So, the user can submit it anytime he/she wants.

In the service, the `getProfile` function is

```
  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', this.token);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  }

  getProfile(user_id){
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/profile/'+user_id, {headers:headers}).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
```

My problem is that node.js says in the console `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` every time I refresh.

Is this because of my code and the ability to submit at anytime constantly ? How can I fix this? I should be able to set the same headers once and use them in every future `getProfile` call. I tried something like

```
  createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
    headers.append('Authorization', this.token);
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
  }
    let headers = new Headers();
    this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

  getProfile(user_id){
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/profile/'+user_id, {headers:headers}).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
```

but then angular says `'return' outside of function` about the `getProfile`.

Little help here?

Thanks

**EDIT**

From the node point , this is the route that I hit with angular

```
router.get('/:userid', validate.required(), (req, res)=>{ 
  user.query('select firstname from user WHERE id = $1', [req.params.userid])
  .then((resolved)=>{
      res.json({success:true, data:data });    
   })
   .catch((error)=>{
     res.json({success:false, msg:errorvalue});
   });
});
```

and this is the `validate` middleware

```
  exports.required = ()=>{
    return (req, res,next)=>{
      const token = req.get('Authorization');
      const key = config.key;
      jwt.verify(token, key,function(err, decoded) {
        if (err){res.json({redirect:true});}
        if (decoded){
          let dateNow = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
          if (dateNow > decoded.exp){res.json({redirect:true});}
          next();
        }
        else {res.json({redirect:true});}
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you're having a NodeJS error, then it's not an Angular error. Is your API using NodeJS ?

Comment: *Little help here?* - don't use Angular app to debug backend problems. This provides unnecessary moving parts. If it's Node problem (it likely is), ask a question that is specific to Node and provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You should be able to replicate the problem with regular Postman request, minus the whole Angular stuff.

Comment: Yes , I am hitting an node API I created. What node code should I post ? This route is protected by a route-specific middleware that checks the headers for tokens

Answer (score 0):

just like the error says: You are setting the headers but the server already sent the response. you need to set the headers earlier in the call chain.

if you want an example look at my repo here:

https://github.com/Robbie106gti/nc-catalog/blob/master/functions/auth/login.js